# remove scientific notation renjin

Tags: r, renjin

In the output of an R code in the renjin I get scientific notation. I adjusted the options for scientific notation, however it did not succeed:

For example:

```
test <- 20160430
options("scipen"=999, "digits"=10, "OutDec"= ".")
print("scipen")
print(getOption("scipen", default = NULL))
print("digits")
print(getOption("digits", default = NULL))
print("test")
print(test)
```

Gives in renjin/java:
2.0160430E7

Running this code in R gives, as expected:
20160430

Any thoughts?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `options` to disable scientific notation:

```
options(scipen=999)
```

Comment: Unfortunately also 999 does not work in Renjin (in the regular R software both 100 and 999 do work)

Comment: Ok. Thank you. I will remove my answer. Maybe you should add that info to your question. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Changing the input datatype in java from decimal to float solved the problem

Answer (score 1):

In this case, Renjin does not respect the session options when formatting. I've opened [Issue #172](https://github.com/bedatadriven/renjin/issues/172) with your example.